# Error al agregar otro registro a la tabla de ventas (no insert en SQL) me da error, con livewire y laravel

Tags: php, laravel, livewire

Hola buen día compañeros.

Espero tengan un buen día. Espero me puedan ayudar.

tengo un problema.... aca.

es una vista de ventas, donde en la caja le doy la clave del producto y al darle clic al boton me agrega el registro en la tabla. cuando agrego 1 registro esta bien, pero cuando quiero poner 2 es cuando me da el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve al agregar 1 registro a la tabla no genera error. hasta ahí todo bien.

cuando agrego otro registro es el problema.

me da este error.

**Attempt to read property "id" on array**

esta parte la estoy haciendo con livewire. La parte de la vista es la siguiente.

**Codigo de la vista**

```
<div>
<x-input-label for="agregar" :value="__('Producto')" />
<x-text-input id="agregar" class="inline-block mt-1 text-center" type="number" wire:model.lazy="clave" required />

<x-primary-button class="ml-2 mlr-3 tran" wire:click="seleccionar">
    {{ __('Agregar producto') }}
</x-primary-button>


<div class="overflow-x-auto">
    <table class="my-5 w-full border-collapse bg-white shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg table-auto">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">Clave</th>
                <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">Grupo</th>
                <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">Marca</th>
                <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">¿cuantos?</th>
                <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">existencias</th>
                <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">Precio venta</th>
                <th class="py-2 px-4 border-b">subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="agregartb" name="agregartb">
                @foreach ($filas as $da)
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{$da->id}}</td>
                        <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{$da->Grupo}}</td>
                        <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{$da->Marca}}</td>

                        <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">
                            <x-text-input id="cantidad" class="inline-block mt-1 text-center" type="number"
                                wire:model="cuantos"
                                value='1'
                                min="1"/>
                        </td>

                        <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">{{$da->Existencia}}</td>
                        <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">
                            <x-text-input id="dineros" class="inline-block mt-1 text-center" type="number"
                                wire:model="valor"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="py-2 px-4 border-b">
                            <x-text-input id="subtotal" class="inline-block mt-1 text-center" type="number"
                                wire:model="subtotal" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<x-input-label for="total" :value="__('Total de la venta')" />
<x-text-input id="total" class="inline-block mt-1" type="text" name="text" required />
```

del 1er **x-text-input** obtengo la clave.

y en la clase lo tengo asi ...

**Clase**

```
<?php
```

class Ventas extends Component
{

```
public $clave; #<-- del Input clave.

#--------------------------#
#--------- array ----------#
#--------------------------#

public $filas = [];

#--------------------------#
#----- datos a poner ------#
#--------------------------#

public $cuantos; #<-- existencias de un producto
public $valor; #<-- costo de un producto
public $subtotal; #antes del total de toda la compra.

#--------------------------#
#----- variable datos -----#
#--------------------------#

protected $datos;

#-------metodos--------#


public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.ventas');
}

public function seleccionar(){ #<-- metodo de wire:click cuando le den click al boton
    $datos = DB::table('productos')
        ->select('id','Grupo','Marca','Existencia','Precio_vta')
        ->where('id',$this->clave)
        ->first();


    // dd($this->datos);

    $this->valor= $datos->Precio_vta; #<-- accedo al valor del objeto precio vta

    $this->clave = ""; # la caja clave se pone vacia.

    $this->cuantos = 1; # la caja de cauntos se pone 1

    array_push($this->filas, $datos); #agrego la siguiente fila. 
    dd($this->filas);

    $this->calcularSubt(); # se calcula el subtotal
}

public function calcularSubt(){
    $this->subtotal = $this->cuantos * $this->valor;
}
```

}

cuando hago el dd

al principio me sale esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando le mando otra vez la clave si me regresa información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta raro , no se si es por que no se inserta correctamente el objeto en el array, oh si lo estoy haciendo mal.

Ustedes que son más conocedores y con más experiencia ¿me pueden auxiliar?

por favor y adelantándome muchas gracias.

cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

Comment: Y cuando hacés un dd de $this->clave que te aparece?

Comment: @JavierSnachez sale el valor que le mando ya sea 1 o 2, pero en este caso se limpia el valor de la caja.